# Angular how to know if a request has timeout more than three times?

Tags: angular, http, timeout, httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I have an **Angular 4 app** that has a lot of ongoing **http request** when navigating through the entire app.

I also want to do something when the http timeout happened three times or more.

There are other errors in an http request that might happen but I only want to focus on the timeout error.

I have this code below in my **http_interceptor**.

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const re = '/u/auth/login';
    const defaultTimeout = 10000;

    if (req.url.search(re) || req.url.search('api.giphy.com/v1') === -1) {
        const headers = new HttpHeaders({
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
            // 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        })
        const dupReq = req.clone({headers});
        const timeOut = Number(req.headers.get('timeout')) || this.defaultTimeout
        return next.handle(dupReq).pipe(
          timeout(timeOut),
          catchError(e => {
            return of(null)
          })
        )
    } else {
        return next.handle(req)
    }
  }
```

How can I handle timeout errors and how can I know that they happened three times or more. Will I do an increment on each error? and just use a condition to do that function?

As a bonus question how can I also success callback handle to the interceptor?

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> chained retryWhen method just above subscribe method.

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/retryWhen';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/scan';

.retryWhen((err)=> {
        return err.scan((attempt) => {
            if(attempt>5){
                throw(err);
            }else{
                attempt++;
                console.log("attempt number "+attempt);
                return attempt;
            }
        },0
        ).delay(1000)
    })
```

Comment: I tried it like this `return next.handle(dupReq).pipe(
          timeout(timeOut),
          catchError(e => {
            return of(e)
          }),
          retryWhen(err => {
            return err.scan(attempt => {
              if (attempt > 5) {
                throw(err);
              } else {
                  attempt++;
                  console.log("attempt number "+attempt);
                  return attempt;
              }
            }, 0)
          }).delay(1000)
        )` But I got an error The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's